# How can I write JavaScript cookies to keep the data persistent after page reloads on my form?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to learn how to write cookies to keep the data in my CookieButton1 button persistent and to survive refreshes and page reloads. How can I do this in JavaScript?
I have supplied my source code. Any advise, links or tutorials will be very helpful.
If you navigate to [http://iqlusion.net/test.html][1] and click on Empty1, it will start to ask you questions. When finished it stores everything into CookieButton1. But when I refresh my browser the data resets and goes away.

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>no_cookies>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)

{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
}

    function getCookie(c_name)

{
if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
  c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  if (c_start!=-1)
    {
    c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
    c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
    if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
  }
return "";
}

    function checkCookie()

{
CookieButton1=getCookie('CookieButton1');
if (CookieButton1!=null && CookieButton1!="")
  {
  alert('Welcome again '+CookieButton1+'!');
  }
else
  {

  if (CookieButton1!=null && CookieButton1!="")
    {
    setCookie('CookieButton1',CookieButton1,365);
    }
  }
}

var Can1Set = "false";

function Can1()
{
   if (Can1Set == "false")
   {
      Can1Title = prompt("What do you want to name this new canned response?","");
      Can1State = prompt("Enter a ticket state (open or closed)","closed");
      Can1Response = prompt("Enter the canned response:","");
      Can1Points = prompt("What point percentage do you want to assign? (0-10)","2.5");

      // Set the "Empty 1" button text to the new name the user specified
      document.CookieTest.CookieButton1.value = Can1Title;

      // Set the cookie here, and then set the Can1Set variable to true
      document.cookie = "CookieButton1"; 
      alert(document.cookie); 

      Can1Set = true;
   }else{
      document.TestForm.TestStateDropDownBox.value = Can1State;
      document.TestForm.TestPointsDropDownBox.value = Can1Points;
      document.TestForm.TestTextArea.value = Can1Response;

      // document.TestForm.submit();

   }
}
</script>

<form name=TestForm>
State: <select name=TestStateDropDownBox>
<option value=new selected>New</option>
<option value=open selected>Open</option>
<option value=closed>Closed</option>

</select>

Points: <select name=TestPointsDropDownBox>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=1.5>1.5</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=2.5>2.5</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=3.5>3.5</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=4.5>4.5</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
<option value=5.5>5.5</option>
<option value=6>6</option>
<option value=6.5>6.5</option>
<option value=7>7</option>
<option value=7.5>7.5</option>
<option value=8>8</option>
<option value=8.5>8.5</option>
<option value=9>9</option>
<option value=9.5>9.5</option>
<option value=10>10</option>
</select>
<p>

Ticket information:<br>
<textarea name=TestTextArea cols=50 rows=7></textarea>
</form>

<form name=CookieTest>

<input type=button name=CookieButton1 value="Empty 1" onClick="javascript:Can1()">

</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any server side code language?

Comment: Not right now. I am using .php scripts on other projects though.
I searched google for javascript cookies and found multiple working examples. Problem is I have trouble integrating them into this code. Nothing I have done so far seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the cookie here, and then set the Can1Set variable to true
document.CookieTest.CookieButton1 = "CookieButton1";
```

You aren't setting the cookie here. You are attempting to change the button element with the name `CookieButton1` of the form with the name `CookieTest` to a String value `"CookieButton1"`. This would have shown a JavaScript error in the average webbrowser.

To set a real cookie, you need [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie). You can find a little tutorial at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: Looking at the two links you provided now. Thanks for bringing this up to my attention.

Comment: I checked the links you provided. I have followed the tutorials and still cannot seem to write cookies for my form.

I wrote the three functions function setCookie, function getCookie and function checkCookie(). I have also updated my source code output above. Dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

document.cookie = "CookieButton1";

All that is doing is setting a cookie without a value, only a name. Cookies are defined as a 'name=value' pairing.

It should look like this ( or equivalent )
document.cookie = 'cookieID=CookieButton1';

Setting document.cookie = will NOT overwrite existing cookies, simply append information to the established cookie.

If you wanted to delete all cookies set by YOUR domain you can always use the following script

```
function delCookie() {
    var new_date = new Date()
    new_date = new_date.toGMTString()
    var thecookie = document.cookie.split(";")
    for (var i = 0; i < thecookie.length; i++) {
        document.cookie = thecookie[i] + "; expires =" + new_date
    }
}
```

If you need to remove cookies individually, the removeCookie function you have will suffice, but only if it is in a name=value pairing. Else your cookie is unusable since it will contain no data just a name.

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie value works as far as saving the data yes, however once you click refresh the `can1set` variable is set back to the value of `false` so the browser is seeing it as `null` when it runs the `checkCookie()` function. In my chat program im currently working on I had a simular issue until I set a variable in my `checkCookie()` function to check against. That way i wasn't always checking against a `false` value and returning `null` to my if statement.

like so...

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
    //if username is NOT null and is not blank asigns it to idname
  document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML= document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML +=  username;
  }
else 
  {
     //if username IS null or blank prompt  user to enter name
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,1);
    }
  else
    {
     //if user submits a null or blank value close browser
    byebye();
    }
  }
}
```